# Pass HTML id in another web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I try to display crystal report in `Report.aspx`. so for this first i create class "``report_class` and in that class i create function like this:

using cookies

in webform2 i try this

```
  public static bool setCookiesValue(Page page, string cookiesName, string cookiesValue, ref string ermsg)
    {
        if (cookiesValue.Trim().Length < 1)
        {
            ermsg = "cookies empty";
            return false;
        }


        HttpCookie clearCookies = page.Request.Cookies[cookiesName];
        clearCookies[cookiesName] = cookiesValue;
        clearCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
        page.Response.Cookies.Add(clearCookies);
        return true;
    }



    public static String getCookies(Page page, string cookiesName)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpCookie GetCookies = page.Request.Cookies[cookiesName];
            return GetCookies[cookiesName].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {

            return string.Empty;
        }

    }
```

then on button click

```
 protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


       string datef = string.Empty;
        setCookiesValue(this, "fromdate", "todate","regiondrop", ref ret);
            report_class r = new report_class();
            Report_Detail report = new Report_Detail();
            Response.Redirect("Reports.aspx");

        }
        catch
        {
            Label4.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

and in reports.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Report_Detail report = new Report_Detail();
            report_class r = new report_class();
            string date_f = getCookies(this, "fromdate");
            string date_t = getCookies(this, "todate");
            string drop_r = getCookies(this, "regiondrop");
            r.Bindreport_class(report, Convert.ToDateTime(date_f),   
            Convert.ToDateTime(date_t), Convert.ToString(drop_r));
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
            CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();


        }
```

but this show error

```
Error   8   No overload for method 'setCookiesValue' takes 5 arguments  
Error   3   The name 'getCookies' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: you mean, you need a parameter in CR? give an example..

Comment: cr?????????????????

Comment: Crystal Report Buddy.. it means CR

Comment: no there is already parameter in page i just want to display these value in CR

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the value from for Example form1 to form2:

Do it this way:

FORM2

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public static Label  lblvar= null;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

FORM1:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            Form2.lblvar = lblvarinform1;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblvarinform1.Text = txtdatepicker.Text;
            Form2.lblvar.Text = lblvarinform1.Text;
        }
    }
```

USING COOKIES:

```
 public static bool setCookiesValue(Page page, string cookiesName, string cookiesValue,ref string ermsg)
        {
            if (cookiesValue.Trim().Length < 1)
            {
                ermsg = "cookies empty";
                return false;
            }


                HttpCookie clearCookies = page.Request.Cookies[cookiesName];
                clearCookies[cookiesName] = cookiesValue;
                clearCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
                page.Response.Cookies.Add(clearCookies);
                return true;
        }



 public static String getCookies(Page page,string cookiesName)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpCookie GetCookies = page.Request.Cookies[cookiesName];
                return GetCookies[cookiesName].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {

                return string.Empty;
            }

        }
```

using the function above:

set cookies new value:

```
string ret = string.Empty;
        setCookiesValue(this,"yourcookiesname","thisisyourdatevaue_or_any",ref ret);
```

get cookies value in another form:

```
string getval = getCookies(this,"yourcookiesname");
```

Comment: Another way to this passing variable, you can use cookies too for storing a variable.

Comment: be carefull using session, much better to use cookies than session. session stored value can be use by another user who is accessing your site.

Comment: i use sessions like this . Session["fromdate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate.Value);
                Session["todate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(todate.Value);
                Session["regiondrop"] = regiondrop.SelectedValue;

Comment: wait maybe i could share it to you

Comment: and use these values like this ..             r.Bindreport_class(report,Convert.ToDateTime(Session["fromdate"]),Convert.ToDateTime(Session["todate"]),Convert.ToString(Session["regiondrop"]));

Comment: cookies behavior just for one user per pc only unlike session it could be in server only not on client pc

Comment: this show error  The name 'SetCookiesExpiresByNextDay' does not exist in the current context

Comment: and with the replace of this .. setCookiesValue(Page page, string cookiesName, string cookiesValue, ref string ermsg) i write this setCookiesValue(Page page, Datetime fromdate, Datetime todate,string region, ref string ermsg)????

Comment: what value do you want to use for cookies?

Comment: SetCookiesExpiresByNextDay(page, cookiesName); just remove that one

Comment: i want to use fromdate , todate and region